# Azure AD Graph API returns Unsupported Query for signin activity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rest-api, azureadgraph-deprecation

We are using Azure AD Graph API for collecting signin logs from Azure AD. Suddenly we are not able to use Azure AD Graph API for getting signin logs from Azure AD

```
Activity Log API : https://graph.windows.net/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/activities/audit?api-version=beta (Working fine)
Signin Logs API : https://graph.windows.net/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/activities/signinEvents?api-version=beta

Signin Logs API returns as Unsupported Query
```

[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ami8.png)
[azure ad graph explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsA3t.png)

Comment: Why do you name the 2 same requests to different names? One is "Activity Log API" and  the other is "Signin Logs API"? Did you provide the wrong second request?

Comment: Thanks for updating, Edited question @Allen Wu

Comment: I test the same request in [AAD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#) and it works fine for me. Can you share a screenshot about how you call the API?

Comment: added postman screenshot @Allen Wu

Comment: It also works fine for me in Postman. So what did you set in **Headers**?

Comment: Authorization : Bearer access_token

Comment: Share a screenshot pls.

Comment: What if you call this API in [AAD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#)?

Comment: updated postman screenshot of request header

Comment: Can you show hidden headers?

Comment: updated both AAD explorer and postman hidden headers

Comment: The format is wrong, please edit the post.

Comment: kindly check now

Comment: Very strange. Your request is the same as mine. Did you try it in AAD Graph Explorer I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I tried on AAD Graph Explorer, Same response from AAD Graph Explorer (updated screenshot of AAD graph explorer)

Comment: If so, I guess you need the backend team's help. It's recommended to raise a support ticket on Azure portal.

Comment: Does this API works for your tenant?

Comment: Yes. It works fine for me both in Postman and AAD Graph Explorer.